# Яндекс карты. Как получить равномерно распределенные точки по региону?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

У меня есть координаты границы региона Москвы, и мне необходимо равномерно распределить точки по этому и региону и узнать их координаты.
Есть ли какие то готовые решения такой задачи?

Comment: А Вы умеет проверять вхождение в регион?

Comment: @MBo, нет, не умею

Comment: Наверняка для этого есть какие-то функции в API яндекс-карт или кто-то сделал, поищите.  Проще всего генерировать равномерные точки, например, в окружающем прямоугольника и отметать те, что лежат снаружи региона (полигон.contains?)

Comment: Равномерно - случайно?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, равномерно, с одним интервалом.

Comment: @DmitryFilippov как по сетке?

Comment: @MBo, нужно чтобы четко в регионе были точки, вариант с фигурами уже рассматривал. В апи не могу найти решений

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Вам решение на turf.js, логика как в комментарии господина @MBo

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
    let map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: turf.center(area).geometry.coordinates,
        zoom: 9,
        controls: []
    });
    map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.GeoObject(area))
    var bbox = turf.bbox(area);
    let count = 15
    for (var x=0; x< count; x++){
      for (var y=0; y< count; y++){
        let obj = {geometry: {type:'Point', coordinates:[
            bbox[0] + (bbox[2]-bbox[0])/count*x,  
            bbox[1] + (bbox[3]-bbox[1])/count*y
        ]}};
        if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(obj, area))
        map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.GeoObject(obj))
      }
    }
});


let area = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [37.34527587890625,55.95381321086168],
        [37.32330322265625,55.66209476458093],
        [37.0843505859375,55.593867449197575],
        [37.12005615234375,55.44771083630114],
        [36.8426513671875,55.5099714998319],
        [36.83990478515625,55.39471190628709],
        [37.04315185546875,55.14277943861009],
        [37.42218017578125,55.26972780710658],
        [37.60894775390625,55.56747507540018],
        [37.8973388671875,55.699259616176356],
        [37.8533935546875,55.824430445857764],
        [37.562255859375,55.95381321086168],
        [37.34527587890625,55.95381321086168]
     ]]
  }
}

area.geometry.coordinates[0] = area.geometry.coordinates[0].map(e=>[e[1],e[0]])
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
} 

#map { 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```